# How can I order a table in a loop depending on the highest number in a specific <td>

Tags: php, loops

How can I order lines of a table depending on the highest number in a loop like this :

```
<?php
while ($d = $data->fetch()) {
$champs_files = fopen("champions/".$champion."_".$d['user_id'].".txt", "r");
$mastery_points = fread($champs_files,filesize("champions/".$champion."_".$d['user_id'].".txt"));
fclose($champs_files);
?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $rank += 1 ?></td>

        <td><?= $d['user_name'] ?></td>

        <td><?= $mastery_points ?></td>

        <td><?= $d['user_region'] ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

I want to put at the top the line who has the biggest $mastery_points .

I can't use MySql cause I have limited number of tables thats why I use files .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to store this data in an array than use sort function on it and display results with foreach function.

```
<?php    
//compare function used for sort
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['mastery_points'] == $b['mastery_points']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['mastery_points'] < $b['mastery_points']) ? -1 : 1;
}

//collect data
$users = [];
while ($d = $data->fetch()) {
    $champs_files = fopen("champions/".$champion."_".$d['user_id'].".txt", 
"r");
    $mastery_points = fread($champs_files,filesize("champions/".$champion."_".$d['user_id'].".txt"));
    fclose($champs_files);
    $users[] = $d + ['mastery_points' => $mastery_points];
}

//sort
usort($users, "cmp");

//show data
foreach ($users as $d) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $rank += 1 ?></td>

        <td><?= $d['user_name'] ?></td>

        <td><?= $d['mastery_points'] ?></td>

        <td><?= $d['user_region'] ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: There is one more problem how can I inverse the order ?

Comment: change the cmp function :P
return ($a['mastery_points'] < $b['mastery_points']) ? 1 : -1;